# Can i use multiple admob account from single ip?

Tags: android, admob

I am a game developer and i use google admob to display ads in my apps. I have one confusion regarding admob.My question is , can i access two different admob account from a single pc.

Let me give you a scenario, My co-workers also developing apps.So they also have their admob account.We use same internet connection when developing apps. Now Suppose I create admob banner id from Computer A.Then my friend creates id for his account from Computer A. Then is there any chances to account getting suspended? I heard that they block account from same ip address. I am not good at English so sorry if i made any mistake. Hope you understand the question

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use multiple AdMob accounts from single IP.

for example, if a person has opened his AdMob account in the cyber cafe and then he logged out. After his, anyone can open different AdMob account on the same IP.
So it's valid. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is admob have this kind of specification on there support page..?? If I could have confirmation then it would be great.

Comment: No AdMob doesn't have this kind of specification.

Comment: Can I delete/cancel my current account and open new account with same email id.

Answer (score 2):

yes it can be opened , as its clearly mentioned in ad mob policies, you can connect multiple ad mob account having different Gmail ids, not of single person but should be different persons ids, can connect to one internet. Same system, same IP address.

1.its mentioned in ad mob policies ,some under developed country facing this issue having only one internet connection, and only one system, so you can connect to same IP address, google just demands different ids,

2. IP address matter when single person having account with different Gmail ids, and same bio data, contact number ,recovery email, then its matter otherwise  its not matter.third parties can connect easily up to as you can connect.

Comment: Can I delete/cancel my current account and open new account with same email id.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different accounts from same IP. But it has to be different person. If you create multiple accounts and use from same IP, Google may ban your all accounts. So be careful.

Comment: Can I delete/cancel my current account and open new account with same email id.